# basic code sample to create service principal in tenant?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I made an app that is designed to run as a service without user intervention. (it works correctly in my own AAD, it does oAuth call and gets a token and everything is lovely ;))

It's application object lives in my Azure active directory and is configured as multi tenant and has a client secret.

Now I want to get it listed in another AAD tenant and be permitted to access data. Idealy I would want to have a helper application with a button to click after which my app is authorized to run from the users' AAD and access their data/api.
From what I read, the granting of the permissions by an admin would create a service principal in the admin's AAD and i'm done.

Can anybody help me with the code that I can call with the "magic" button?

Answer (score 0):

You essentially need to get you code to work with the [Request the permissions from a directory admin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-admin-consent#request-the-permissions-from-a-directory-admin) process. Now that step is at almost the very end of a much involved process.

Multi-tenancy and service principal provisioning across tenants is a fairly involved process actually, so providing links to some material that would help walk you through those.

1. [Sign in any Azure Active Directory user using the multi-tenant application pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant)
2. [Develop multi-tenant applications with Microsoft identity platform](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B416AxHoMJ4&ab_channel=Microsoft365Developer)
3. [Integrate a multi-tenant SaaS web application that calls Microsoft Graph](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-3-Multi-Tenant/README.md) (aspnet core sample for a web App)
4. [Multi-tenant (SaaS) Angular single-page application that authenticates users with Azure AD and calls a protected ASP.NET Core web API](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-angular-tutorial/blob/main/6-Multitenancy/1-call-api-mt/README.md) (Javascript sample)
5. [Protect a multi-tenant SaaS web application and a Web API which calls Microsoft Graph on-behalf of the user with the Microsoft Identity Platform](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-3-AnyOrg/Readme.md) (aspnet core with a WebAPI)

Comment: thanks for your help. i managed to do it in the powershell with new-AzureADServicePrincipal